# unable to reacquire mutex and pass values correctly between threads

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I am trying to implement a code to practice synchronization, so might not be best design or approach but goal is as below

- Main thread

  1. Creates a payload of 100 integers and waits for any thread to be available
  2. When it gets signal from a thread its available - it unlocks the payload for copying and proceeds to create another payload
- Worker thread

  1. on creation of it makes itself available for data processing and sends signal that its available
  2. Tries to lock the data payload from main thread and copy it to local array
     ( observing bug here - not able to access data properly)
  3. Turn off the sign of available
     ( unable to turn off available state to off)
  4. Keep processing data through local copy

---

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define WORKERS 2
#define ARRAY_ELEMENTS 100
#define MAX 1000


pthread_mutex_t mutex_bucket1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_signal = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_go = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_busy = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

static int value = 0;
bool available = false;

void *worker_thread(void *pbucket)
{
    sleep(5);
    while(1)
    {
        unsigned int count = 0;
        int local_array[ARRAY_ELEMENTS];
        int *ptbucket = (int*)pbucket;
        setbuf(stdout, NULL);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_signal);
        printf(" --------------   \n chainging state to available \n --------- ");
        available = true;
        printf(" --------------   \n from thread sending go signal \n --------- ");
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_go);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_signal);


        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_bucket1);
        printf(" --------------   \n data part locked in thread for copying \n --------- ");
        while(count < ARRAY_ELEMENTS)
        {
            printf(" %d - \n", ptbucket[count]);  /***incorrect values***/
            local_array[count] = ptbucket[count];
            count++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_bucket1);

        /*Never able to acquire mutex_signal and change state to not available*/   **BUG**
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_signal);
        printf(" --------------   \n chainging state to not available \n --------- ");
        available = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_signal);

        count = 0;

        while(count < ARRAY_ELEMENTS)
        {
            printf(" %d - \n", local_array[count]);
            count++;
        }

        printf(" --------------   \n about to sleep for 5secs \n --------- ");
        sleep(5);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread_id[WORKERS];

    unsigned int* pbucket1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_ELEMENTS);

    unsigned int* pbucket;

    for(int i = 0; i < WORKERS - 1; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, worker_thread, (void *) pbucket);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        unsigned int count = 0;

        pbucket = pbucket1;

        // Make the payload ready
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_bucket1);

        printf(" -------------- creating data payload --------- \n");

        while(count < ARRAY_ELEMENTS)
        {
            pbucket1[count] = i;
            i++;
            count++;
        }

        printf(" --------------   \n waiting for go signal \n --------- ");

        while(!available)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_go, &mutex_signal);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_bucket1);

        /*I believe after we unlock variable "available" can be mutexed
          again by other thread but seems thinking is flawed */

        printf(" --------------   \n Main thread sleep for 3 seconds  \n --------- ");
        sleep(3);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < WORKERS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf` does not synchronize against multiple threads. You have multiple threads using it on top of each other.

Comment: @eok - I have tried to induce sleep artificially  to buy time .. also for current code I have kept thread count to only 1 and still unable to achieve any meaningful results

Comment: I also commented all but 1 printf - for printing numbers and still get the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some of your idea is backwards; It shouldn't be the main context that is waiting, it should be the worker threads waiting for data ...

The job of the main thread should be to keep populating the payload and waking one thread at a time to process it.

So here's some scribbled code that is a little more sensible, I think:

```
/**
    file: answer.c
    compile: gcc -o answer answer.c -pthread
    usage: answer [numThreads] [numElements]
**/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define STATE_WAIT    1
#define STATE_READY   2

void *routine(void*);

typedef struct _shared_t {
    pthread_mutex_t     m;
    pthread_cond_t      c;
    unsigned char       state;
    int                 *payload;
    size_t              numElements;
    pthread_t           *threads;
    size_t              numThreads;
} shared_t;

static inline void shared_init(shared_t *shared, size_t numThreads, size_t numElements) {
    memset(shared, 0, sizeof(shared_t));

    pthread_mutex_init(&shared->m, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&shared->c, NULL);

    shared->state = STATE_WAIT;

    shared->numThreads = numThreads;
    shared->numElements = numElements;

    {
        int it = 0;

        shared->threads = (pthread_t*) calloc(shared->numThreads, sizeof(pthread_t));

        while (it < shared->numThreads) {
            if (pthread_create(&shared->threads[it], NULL, routine, shared) != 0) {
                break;
            }
            it++;
        }
    }
}

static inline void shared_populate(shared_t *shared) {
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->m) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    shared->payload = (int*) calloc(shared->numElements, sizeof(int));  

    {
        int it = 0,
             end = shared->numElements;

        while (it < end) {
            shared->payload[it] = rand();

            it++;
        }
    }

    shared->state = STATE_READY;

    pthread_cond_signal(&shared->c);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->m);
}

static inline void shared_cleanup(shared_t *shared) {
    int it = 0,
         end = shared->numThreads;

    while (it < end) {
        pthread_join(shared->threads[it], NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&shared->m);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&shared->c);

    free(shared->threads);
}

void* routine(void *arg) {
    shared_t *shared = (shared_t*) arg;
    int *payload;

    do {
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->m) != 0) {
            break;
        }

        while (shared->state == STATE_WAIT) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&shared->c, &shared->m);
        }

        payload = shared->payload;

        shared->state = STATE_WAIT;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->m);

        if (payload) {
            int it = 0,
                 end = shared->numElements;

            while (it < end) {
                printf("Thread #%ld got payload %p(%d)=%d\n", 
                    pthread_self(), payload, it, payload[it]);
                it++;
            }

            free(payload);
        }
    } while(1);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    shared_t shared;

    int numThreads = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    int numElements   = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 100;

    shared_init(&shared, numThreads, numElements);

    do {
        shared_populate(&shared);
    } while (1);

    shared_cleanup(&shared);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the code above is not very tolerant of errors, and is not easy to shutdown cleanly ... it's illustration only.

Let's first look at `main` so that we know what the flow of the main program is going to be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    shared_t shared;

    int numThreads = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    int numElements   = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 100;

    shared_init(&shared, numThreads, numElements);

    do {
        shared_populate(&shared);
    } while (1);

    shared_cleanup(&shared);

    return 0;
}
```

It keeps a `shared_t` on the stack:

```
typedef struct _shared_t {
    pthread_mutex_t     m;
    pthread_cond_t      c;
    unsigned char       state;
    int                 *payload;
    size_t              numElements;
    pthread_t           *threads;
    size_t              numThreads;
} shared_t;
```

Mostly self explanatory, mutex, condition and state are required for synchronization.

First of all the `shared_t` must be initialized with mutex, condition, state and threads using the provided options:

```
static inline void shared_init(shared_t *shared, size_t numThreads, size_t numElements) {
    memset(shared, 0, sizeof(shared_t));

    pthread_mutex_init(&shared->m, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&shared->c, NULL);

    shared->state = STATE_WAIT;

    shared->numThreads = numThreads;
    shared->numElements = numElements;

    {
        int it = 0;

        shared->threads = (pthread_t*) calloc(shared->numThreads, sizeof(pthread_t));

        while (it < shared->numThreads) {
            if (pthread_create(&shared->threads[it], NULL, routine, shared) != 0) {
                break;
            }
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```

When the worker threads are created by this routine, they are forced into a waiting state.

The first call to `shared_populate` in the loop awakens the first thread after setting the payload to some random numbers:

```
static inline void shared_populate(shared_t *shared) {
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->m) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    shared->payload = (int*) calloc(shared->numElements, sizeof(int));  

    {
        int it = 0,
             end = shared->numElements;

        while (it < end) {
            shared->payload[it] = rand();

            it++;
        }
    }

    shared->state = STATE_READY;

    pthread_cond_signal(&shared->c);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->m);
}
```

Note the use of `pthread_cond_signal` over `pthread_cond_broadcast`, because we only want to wake the first thread.

```
void* routine(void *arg) {
    shared_t *shared = (shared_t*) arg;
    int *payload;

    do {
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&shared->m) != 0) {
            break;
        }

        while (shared->state == STATE_WAIT) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&shared->c, &shared->m);
        }

        payload = shared->payload;

        shared->state = STATE_WAIT;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared->m);

        if (payload) {
            int it = 0,
                 end = shared->numElements;

            while (it < end) {
                printf("Thread #%ld got payload %p(%d)=%d\n", 
                    pthread_self(), payload, it, payload[it]);
                it++;
            }

            free(payload);
        }
    } while(1);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So we wake up in `routine` at the call to `pthread_cond_wait`, the state has changed, so we break out of the loop, we save the pointer to the payload, reset the state to WAIT, and release the mutex.

At this point `main` can repopulate the payload and awaken the next thread, meanwhile the current worker thread can process, and then free the payload.

Some advice:

- Always use as few mutex and condition variables as possible (KISS)
- Research the atomic nature of condition variables
- Always follow the basic rules regarding acquisition and release of mutex and signaling of condition variables:

  - If you locked it, unlock it.
  - Only ever wait *for* something: predicated wait loops are absolutely required, all the time.

If you can't reproduce what I done, then take the code and try to expand upon it; The first thing you need to do is be able to shutdown the process gracefully (enter `shared_cleanup`), maybe you need a variable sized payload, or some other requirement not mentioned in the original question.

*Note about `printf` ... appending to a stream is not guaranteed to be atomic, it so happens that most of the time on *nix it is ... since we are just doing show and tell, we don't need to care about that ... ordinarily, do not rely on atomicity for any stream operations ...*

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference code and explanation. Surely its more clearly designed and makes more sense. Can you please also point me to why in my code , y I am not able to reacquire the mutex ? It would also help me to understand more clearly the locking and unlocking mechanism